# Explorer.exe: No such interface supported

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Lately Windows 7 has been throwing these weird errors at me and refusing to open certain applications. From what I've managed to figure out, the problem might be a lost dll.

**Errors:**

While trying to open up "Screen resolution", "Personalize",  from the desktop, it throws back an error with "Explorer.EXE" in the title saying "No such interface supported". All I can do is to agree with "Ok".

When programs such as Microsoft Visual studio tries to open up Explorer.exe to open a file it will fail due to unknown reasons. "The operation could not be completed".

Trying to open up certain windows ("Join a Personal Area Network" and "Show bluetooth devices") for Bluetooth activities, the window just won't open up, while others open up in an instance.

Several activities in the Control panel won't work either, such as "Uninstall program", "Adjust screen resolution" (wont work from here either :p)

---

I'm really clueless where to look or what to do right now, except for re-installing the whole thing, which I rather not spend my weekend doing. Help? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Have you installed some product just before this started happening?
   If yes, it might be the cause of the problem. An uninstallation is the best way to verify.
2. Try to boot in Safe mode (F8 during Windows startup). In this mode only Windows components are allowed to startup. If the problem disappears, then it's some installed product that's causing it. Download [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), save a system restore point, and then use it to serially block products from starting with Windows, until you find the guilty one.
3. Based on the premise that something went wrong with your own account that prevents you from executing some programs, the solution would be to create a new user profile and abandon your old one.
4. Based on the premise that some dll went wrong, and if you have a real Windows installation DVD (meaning not just a restore one), you might try to do an upgrade installation. This would do an upgrade of your system to itself, meaning nothing, but will re-establish any wrong dlls.
5. The last-ditch effort would be to re-install Windows. But wait with this until some more ideas for solutions come in from others on this forum.

Comment: 1) I've installed various programs, can't remember which was which. I can't open up windows Uninstall-dialog, so I can't really figure it out. 2) Didn't work 3) I can't create new user accounts, since that dialog won't open up either. 4) I tried their "repair my computer"-thingy, it couldn't help me. 5) This will work but it's a bit of a hassle.

Comment: 1) Try to use Revo Uninstaller : http://www.revouninstaller.com/. 2) Then this is a problem with Windows itself. 3) See this : http://www.technibble.com/an-easy-way-to-brea-into-a-windows-user-account/. 4) I meant Upgrade as in http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/2582d1231747597-upgrade-install-windows-7-step6.jpg.

Comment: I'm doing a full virus scan at the moment, I will try an upgrade tomorrow. Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Note: Your answer (2) invalidates the need for (1). We should now concentrate on (3) and (4).

Comment: An upgrade install solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Not virus  it is permissions problem you need to go into registry and correct the permissions for hkeyclasses root . Add the current user to the permissions of CLSID and give at least read access. For correct instructions go search for no such interface supported on sevenforums.com

Answer (score 0):

I would personally see if a system restore works, and failing that, do a re install of Windows.

This is not the sort of error that happens every day, it must of been caused by some sort of failure and even though there are methods that may be able to fix it, if you do not know what caused it - it could lead to problems later on.

Comment: I've been dragging my feet with this problem, and as I recall it started to occur 3-4 weeks ago.. my system restore points apparently doesn't go that far back.

Answer (score 0):

there is a corrupted or missing system file, so **SFC /SCANNOW** may help you recover them.

Answer (score 0):

We have had two such issues. Same exact problem. Doing a system restore back to a time before the problem existed fixed the problem. It seems a Microsoft update caused the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue on Windows 2012, where it suddenly stopped opening ***Explorer.exe*** on Windows logon, and displayed a black desktop.
Any attempt to load Explorer.exe failed with error "***No such interface supported***".

I found a solution in http://www.w7forums.com/threads/no-such-interface-supported.17543/ :

From Task Manager (CTRL + SHIFT + ESC), open CMD and run:

```
FOR /R C:\Windows\ %G IN (*.dll) DO "%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "%G"
```

It will take some time and will open many Runtime errors messages, you can close them all.
Once completed, restart windows ( `shutdown -r -t 0` ), and hold fingers...

Answer (score 0):

In reference to all of the above, thanks.Great ideas, but I've found the only way you can really fix this issue is with a Restore to a working restore Point.Pain in the butt but it works perfectly for me.As I Purposely create restore points once a week.This problem was caused FYI by a "Scam" software I bought called, Advanced System Repair. BEWARE of this software,it really destroys a lot of things.Running Win7, i7 CPU,32ram etc.Hope this helps someone,and I recommend creating restore points on a schedule base for sure.
Jim